# Opening youtube links gives activityNotFound Error Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, error-handling

So i have made an app that has the best youtube videos to learn programming.

So youtube has two ways to gives its links,

For example:

The full link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwS1r1mc888
 and

The shortened link : https://youtu.be/QwS1r1mc888

now i have stored all the video links in the firebase database, i have saved all the shortened video links, now on my play console i notices people are getting ActivityNotFound Errors when they try to open these links.

The code i have used to open the video :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(currentUrl));
startActivity(i);
```

Now even the people who have browsers and youtube installed are getting this error/exception. So what should i do ? will storing the whole links help or using shortened link and full links in the same thing ?

How do i overcome this error ?

Comment: Android application needs only the video id speicifically only: `QwS1r1mc888`

Comment: So i have t he video id, how do i call an intent to open youtube

Comment: according to youtube documentation you need to pass on the link to youtuethumbnailview.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications